# Having trouble with Google maps from PHP on Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: php, firefox, google-maps, ubuntu

I have a little PHP application in which I am attempting to display Google maps from within the code as a hyperlink. Like so:-

```
$display_block .= "<td><a href=\"http://maps.google.co.uk/maps?f=q&hl=en&geocode=&q=".$postcode."\">Map</a></td>";
```

The page is duly assembled and displayed, and hovering with the mouse pointer over the link shows...

```
http://maps.google.co.uk/maps?f=q&hl=en&geocode=&q=NG34 9JW
```

Clicking this link gives a blank. All this is done inside a frameset, in case that's important. Typing the reference directly into the browser leads to a map, as expected. This has previously worked, although I haven't checked it for a  while. It appears to have stopped working when I upgraded to Ubuntu 11.10 (or possibly an update shortly before that) (the browser is Mozilla Firefox 7.0.1).

I suspect some configuration was trampled on during the update but I've no idea where to start looking. Can anyone offer any suggestions or advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with `target` atribbute for example:

```
<a href="..." target="_blank">
```

and use `urlencode()` to make proper url

```
urlencode($postcode)
```

so..

```
$display_block .= "<td><a href=\"http://maps.google.co.uk/maps?f=q&hl=en&geocode=&q=".urlencode($postcode)."\" target=\"_blank\">Map</a></td>";
```